# Web scraping from youtube with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, youtube, nokogiri

I want to scrape all the names of the users who commented below a youtube video.
I'm using ruby and nokogiri.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tntOCGkgt98"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css(".comment-thread-renderer > .comment-renderer").each do |comment|
    name = comment.css("#comment-section-renderer-items .g-hovercard").text

    puts name
end
```

But it's not working, I'm not getting any output, no error either.

Comment: If you're not getting output or an error then you should confirm you're actually receiving the HTML you expect. Turn off Javascript in your browser and look at that page. Do you see the content you want? Use `nokogiri 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tntOCGkgt98'` at the command-line and look around, or use `curl` or `wget` to download the page. If you can't find it, the odds are good it's dynamic HTML and the information you want isn't available unless you use something that can interpret DHTML.

Comment: not really answering your question, but what about API for this?

Answer (score 1):

I won't be able to give you a solution, but at least I can give you a couple of hints that may help you to move forward.

The code you have is not working because the comments section is loaded via an ajax call after the page is loaded. If you do a hard reload in your browser, you will see that there is a spinner icon and a `Loading...` text in the sections comment, waiting for the content to be loaded. When Nokogiri gets the page via the `http` request, it gets the html content that you see *before* the comments are loaded. As a matter of fact the place where the contents will be later added looks like:

```
<div id="watch-discussion" class="branded-page-box yt-card">
  <div id="comment-section-renderer"
    class="comment-section-renderer vve-check"
    data-visibility-tracking="CCsQuy8iEwjr3P3u1uzNAhXIepAKHRV9D8Ao-B0=">
      <div class="action-panel-loading">
        <p class="yt-spinner ">
          <span class="yt-spinner-img  yt-sprite" title="Loading icon">
          </span>
          <span class="yt-spinner-message">Loading...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is the reason why you won't find the `div`s you are looking for, because they aren't part of the html you have.

Looking at the network console in the browser, it seems that the ajax request to get the comments data is being sent to `https://www.youtube.com/watch_fragments_ajax?v=tntOCGkgt98&tr=time&distiller=1&ctoken=EhYSC3RudE9DR2tndDk4wAEAyAEA4AEBGAY%253D&frags=comments&spf=load`. As you can see the `v` parameter is the video id, however there are a couple of caveats:

- There is a `ctoken` param, which you can get by scraping the original page contents. It is inside a `<script>` tag, in the form of 
  `'COMMENTS_TOKEN': "<token>"`.
- However, you still need to send a `session_token` as a form data in the body of the AJAX request (which is a `POST`). That I don't know where is coming from :(.

I think that you will be pushing the limits of Nokogiri here, as AFAIK it is not intended to follow ajax requests or handling Javascript. Maybe [the ruby Selenium driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) is better suited for this.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `name.css("#comment-section..."`

The each statement will iterate over the elements, using the variable `name`.

You may want to use `node` instead of name:

```
doc.css(".comment-thread-renderer > .comment-renderer").each do |node|
    name = node.css("#comment-section-renderer-items .g-hovercard").text

    puts name
end
```

Comment: Actually `comment` is better than`node`. I would try `puts comment`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this](https://rails-html-tags-scraper.herokuapp.com/) rails app using nokogiri to see all the tags that a page has before any javascript is run in the browser. The source code is [here](https://github.com/carlos-peru/scraper), so you can adjust it if you need to add more info about the node in the view.

That can easily tell you if the particular tag element that you are looking for is something you can retrieve without having to do some JS eval.

Most web crawlers don't support client-side rendering, which gives you an idea that it's not a trivial task to execute JS when scraping content.

Comment: If at all possible, answers should *not* rely on external links and contain all relevant code in the answer itself.

Comment: This does not answer the implicit question of the OP: “What am I doing wrong? Where is my mistake?” Telling them how *you* did it is hardly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is a dynamically rendered JavaScript website, though it could be parsed with Nokogiri without using `Selenium` or another package. Try open the Network tab in dev tools, scroll to the comment section, and see what request being send.

You need to make a `post` request in order to fetch comments data. You can preview the output in the "Preview" tab.

[image]

Preview output:

[image]

Which is equivalent to this comment:

[image]

*Note: Since this comment brings very little value, this answer will be updated with the attached code once there will be an available solution.*